# Install sass and compass

Tags: ruby, cmd, sass, compass-sass

I getting an issue working with sass from yesterday so i uninstalled sass and compass

This was command

```
gem uninstall sass
gem uninstall compass
```

After that I tried to install again to get a new version of sass and compass

```
gem install sass
gem install compass
```

But I am getting failed message 
[image]

**My questions are** : How can i re install ? and what is the real issue  I am facing ?

Comment: Why would you think that taking a screenshot of the error so that other users who have the same problem cannot search for it is appropriate?

Comment: Do you know if is necessary install compass with SASS in 2020?

Comment: no need, use node grunt or gulp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gem update --system
gem update
gem list
```

Check package version 
Compass - 1.0.1
sass - 3.4.9